# How to create a hibernate order with properties in another table?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to create an order on a table and one of the items to be 'ordered by' happens to be a property that's in the **one end** of the relationship.
Do I specify the property by the **name of the key**, the **name of the property** (in the foreign table) or the **name of the table?**
Currently have:
`order =  new Order[]{Order.asc("lastControlDate"), Order.asc("idManufacturer"), Order.asc("model")};` where in *idManufacturer* is the foreign key
Thanks

The entities are  **Manufacturer** *1..M* **Car** wherein:

Manufacturer:

```
public class Manufacturer{
    private Long idManufacturer;
    private String name;

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Constructors">
public Manufacturer(){
//getters and setters....

}
```

Car:

```
public class Car {
private long idCar;
private String model;
private Manufacturer manufacturer;
//Constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

order = new Order[]{ Order.desc("manufacturer"), Order.desc("model")};

```
public static List<Car> listCarsByManufacturer(Manufacturer name, Order...orders)throws Exception{
        LinkedList<Criterion> criterions = new LinkedList<Criterion>();
        criterions.add(Restrictions.like("Car.manufacturer", name));

        List<Car> cars =carDAO.findAllCars(criterions, orders);
        return cars;
}
```

Comment: HQL and Criteria never use table and column names. They work on entities. For the rest, show us your entities and your query if you want help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still haven't shown us the query, in `CarDAO.findAllCars()`.

Anyway, here's how you get a list of cars with a retriction on their manufacturer name and an order on their manufacturer ID:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Car.class, "car");
// to add a restriction on a property of manufacturer, you need
// an inner join on manufacturer
c.createAlias("car.manufacturer", "manufacturer"); 
c.add(Restrictions.like("manufacturer.name", name));
// you want to get the car with their manufacturer, so you need a fetch
c.setFetchMode(car.manufacturer", FetchMode.JOIN);
// you want to order by id of manufacturer
c.addOrder(Order.asc("manufacturer.idManufacturer"));
```

All this is very well explained in the [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria).

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get around to that part. It's an old inherited project which is quite heavily layered. I was extracting the relevant parts before I had to leave but you answered my question. I just needed to know how to specify 'the property to be ordered upon' if it is a foreign key. Thanks again.